# How to Change Counter position for SQL field

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a field called IntQID, which is an id for each post that is recorded in the SQL database. If a post is 1533, the next entery will be 1534,1535, etc...

I recently messed up and inserted a manual entry with an ID of 4000. Now the counter has been using that as the last entry, so now new posted are 4001, 4002, 4003.

How do I change the counter to go back to using the next in line after 1533?

Hope this makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: If you do that, don't you run the risk of colliding with 4000 at some point in the future? Is it really that important to not have gaps in the sequence (is the sequence significant for something or is it just an identifier)?

Comment: How are you updating the value - is this by an `UPDATE` statement, or is this an auto_increment column?  And are you asking to reset all of the values to correct the sequence?

Comment: There is no 4000 anymore, I've updated all values...

OMG - it's an auto_increment column. I updated the values that were out of sequence, but now anytime a post from the website is inserter, it's counting from the higher 4000 range rather than the existing 1000 range, where i'd like it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set the auto_increment value to 1533, use:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = 1533;
```

To my knowledge, you can't get the highest existing value for setting it in the `ALTER TABLE` statement without using two queries minimum.

Comment: So, I'd alter the whole table, not just a specific Field? My table name is tblQA and the field is IntQID, so ALTER TABLE tblQA AUTO_INCREMENT = 1533?

Comment: @BigMike: This only affects the auto_increment field - doesn't matter what the name of the column is, because MySQL only allows one auto_increment column per table.

Answer (score 1):

ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = 1000;

Comment: +1: This is valid, setting the auto_increment value is arbitrary.  To me, anyways...